SQL REGEX: How to reference digits followed by ‘x’ at the end of a string?
The strings in the column have other digits in the middle or beginning but I only want the digits at the very end followed by an x. For example, if the string is
23apples7892x

I want to return
7892x

I’ve tried so many ways but keep getting en error or it’ll include all the digits in the string which I don’t want

Show us your best (or current) attempt, and tell us what's wrong with it. Also add a tag for the dbms used.

Will your data always be structured like this (always ending in 1 or more digits followed by x)?  If not, include more examples.

Share us a minimum reproduceable code and if you are using MySQL, postgresql, or ms-sql

Regex is DBMS specific. Tag your choice

This might* do it:
\w*\d*\w+(\d+x)
You said digits are in the middle of beginning, so I understand this to be
abc123abc456x -- in the middle
123abc456x -- at the beginning
in either case, you might want to search:
word characters \w (zero or many) *, zero or many digits, one or many word characters, and finally one or many digits and the x character.
*Without knowing your regex enginer or your sample data, this is a (hopefully correct) guess at what you are asking for.
As others have said, post the errors you are getting, what you have tried, and a set of data showing all possible patterns (if possible) and expect output. Then you will get accurate help.
